# Switch Graphics Cards For Dual Monitor

Tags: windows-8, multiple-monitors, graphics-card

I have a dual monitor. The main screen is 1920x1080 and the second is 1600x900

I ran dxdiag and saw my intel HD 4000 is on the 1080p monitor and my good Radeon gfx card is on the lesser monitor

How do I reverse this?  Windows 8

Comp has 1 hdmi port, other evga

Answer (score 4):

I'd guess, quite naturally, switching the video cards that the monitors are plugged into would work. I'm sure I'm missing something otherwise, since, yes, its supposed to be that simple.